# How does Juju get the private-address of a node

Tags: juju

I have a setup where each node has 2 interfaces:

- One connected to a private network between the nodes
- one connected to a public network.

The communication between Juju (on my laptop) and the nodes should happen on the public network. The communication between the nodes should happen on the private network. Currently, Juju uses the public IP for everything, the public IP is also passed as `private-address` between nodes...

How can I get Juju to use the private IP as `private-address` in relations? Where does Juju get that address from? I'm using the manual provider.

Comment: Could you edit the question and mention which provider you are using? Is this manual provider?

Comment: Manual provider

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly:


1) Go to Clusters page

2) In the interface section, define new interface with your private-network Ip 
addresses ( if you not defined private interface yet)

3) When you are defining new interface for cluster there is "Management" drop-down,
select "DHCP and DNS" , so it means a local private DHCP handles your local private network addresses to be set for new nodes?